# NSAttributedString, TTTAttributedLabel: Underline doesn't work with Autoshrink

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to underline a label using [`TTTAttributedLabel`](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) with the following code:

```
[self.opponentUsername setText:self.opponentUsername.text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] range:(NSRange){0, [mutableAttributedString length]}];
    return mutableAttributedString;
}];
```

It works fine when the Autoshrink is disabled in Interface Builder. However, as soon as I enable Autoshrink, the label loses the white color I have applied in IB and the underline disappears completely.

What am I doing something wrong here? TIA

FYI, answers which offer solutions that use some custom library other than `TTTAttributedLabel` are fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fine.

There is an issue with TTTAttributedLabel which when it shrink the font size, it removed any other attributes applied.

There is a fix for that that will preserve the other attributes while adjusting the size.

Here is my fix:

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/pull/187

Comment: Thanks, I've merged your pull request into my fork. Works great!